# Get jQuery data values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Little bit I struck with jquery. Im trying to get value of data_id and url but I'm not geting. I'm using jquery 1.9.2.

```
<a class="blackc accordion-toggle js-accordion-link js-toggle-icon js-no-pjax {'url':'http://example.com/admin/email_templates/edit/62/168c7cbe9c8db561527fa7d20b8ff304','data_id':'62'}" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-admin-email-template" href="#email-content-62">
```

```
.on('click', 'a.js-accordion-link', function(e) {
        $this = $(this);
        var contentDiv = $this.prop('href');
        $id = $this.attr('data_id');
        $parent_class = $('.js-content-' + $id).parent('div').prop('class');
        $this.children('i').toggleClass("icon-minus");
        if ($parent_class.indexOf('in') > -1) {
            $('.js-content-' + $id).block();
            $.get($this.attr('url'), function(data) {
                $('.js-content-' + $id).html(data).unblock();
                return false;
            });
         }
    })
```

The following methods i used to get data_id and url values. but didnt worked.

```
$this.data('data_id');
$this.attr('data_id');
$this.metadata().data_id;
```

Where is im going wrong...

Comment: Firstly the correct syntax would be `$this.data('id');`. However, and more importantly, that element has no `data-id` attribute...?

Comment: You cant put data stuff in class.

Comment: thanks for suggestion Rory McCrossan. data_id is inside the class. I have used like this already. Now its not working

Comment: As @HarryBomrah says, it's not a good idea to put a serialised object in a class, simply because it's a massive pain to retrieve. You would be better to put the values of the object in it's own data attribute. The code would then just be a couple of lines.

Answer (score 3):

> Where is im going wrong

You are shoving a lump of JavaScript into the middle of a class attribute.

Don't do that.

Use data attributes as you did before.

```
<a class="blackc accordion-toggle js-accordion-link js-toggle-icon js-no-pjax" 
   data-toggle="collapse" 
   data-parent="#accordion-admin-email-template" 
   data-url="http://example.com/admin/email_templates/edit/62/168c7cbe9c8db561527fa7d20b8ff304"
   data-id="62"
   href="#email-content-62">
```

Then you can access them with

```
$this.data('id');
$this.data('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this.attr('data-id'); OR $this.data("id") OR $this.data('id');
```

but first add a `data-id` attribute